# Own configure block method not found in initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lib

I'm trying to make own configuration for my lib code according to this: 
https://robots.thoughtbot.com/mygem-configure-block

lib/imodule/imodule.rb:

```
module Imodule
  class << self
    attr_accessor :configuration
  end

  def self.configure
    self.configuration ||= Configuration.new
    yield(configuration)
  end

  class Configuration
    attr_accessor :api_key
    attr_reader :api_url

    def initialize
      @api_url = 'https://api.test.com'
    end
  end
end
```

initializers/imodule.rb:

```
Imodule.configure do |c|
  c.api_key = '4db6-93b3'
end
```

But I'm getting:

> /home/user/Documents/Projects/imodule/config/initializers/imodule.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': undefined method`configure' for Imodule:Module (NoMethodError)

Comment: did you `require imodule` at the top of your initializer file?

Comment: In such case I get:
`home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in 'require': cannot load such file -- imodule (LoadError)`

Comment: Aha, ok. require `require 'imodule/imodule'` helped! Thanks

Comment: awesome, I posted it in an answer if you wouldn't mind accepting : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code you posted, only if the the code in `lib/imodule/imodule.rb` is not being loaded before it's called in `config/initializers/imodule.rb`.

It looks like this is in a Rails app called `imodule`, so `Imodule` is defined as the app module, explaining why you would have just a `NoMethodError` instead of a `NameError` when your module code isn't loaded.

Rails doesn't automatically require files in your `lib` directory, so adding `require 'imodule/imodule'` at the top of the file will fix the problem.